# Electron scattering to find the nuclear radius

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics, scattering, diffraction, scattering-cross-section

[image]

1. Why we use the minimum diffraction angle here to find the nuclear radius?
   *I know how to find the radius (using the equation $d\sin(\theta)=1.22(\lambda)$)*, but I don't know why we use the first minimum angle.
2. How do you interpret such graph qualitatively? Why the bigger the diffraction angle, the lower the intensity/cross section?
3. How about the graph with multiple minima (As shown below)? How do you interpret the consecutive minima? It can't be a nucleus with multiple radii, right?

[image]

Comment: Time to contemplate what exactly is going on during electron scattering from a nucleus. Why would the cross section be varying with scattering angle?

Comment: Presumably your text beats [this diffraction framework](https://www.southampton.ac.uk/~ab1u06//teaching/phys3002/course/03_diffraction.pdf) to death?

Comment: [Bessel Function in Airy disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_disk#Mathematical_Formulation).